# Python Selenium throws StaleElementReferenceException(The element reference is stale )

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape Stackoverflow using python selenium.

I get `StaleElementReferenceException` for few elements when I try to print the link(href) of each question.

Below is the exception which is seen

`selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.`

I've tried both

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
(By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

and

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

I have already checked few questions and couldn't solve this problem
[StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM: Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136122/staleelementreferenceexception-element-is-no-longer-attached-to-the-dom-seleni)

Code snippet

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//div[@id="tabs"]/a[@class="youarehere"]')))
    print "Page is ready!"
except TimeoutException:
    print "Time exceeded"

noofquestionsperpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//div[@class="page-sizer fr"]/a[@class="page-numbers current"]').text
requirednumberofposts = 30
numberofpagesclick = requirednumberofposts / int(noofquestionsperpage)

print numberofpagesclick
if numberofpagesclick > 1:
    for i in range(numberofpagesclick):
        for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="questions"]/div[@class="question-summary"]'):
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, './/div[@class="summary"]/h3/a')))
                print a.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="summary"]/h3/a').get_attribute('href')
            except Exception, e:
                print str(e).strip()
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '//div[@class="pager fl"]/a[6]/span[@class="page-numbers next"]').click()
        except:
            print "All questons loaded"
```

> Update

Found an alternate way to iterate the questions in stackoverflow,posting the code.Now I'm generating xpath based on div id of each quesion instead of using `questions` webelement which was causing `StaleElementReferenceException` earlier.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//div[@id="tabs"]/a[@class="youarehere"]')))
    print "Page is ready!"
except TimeoutException:
    print "Time exceeded"

noofquestionsperpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//div[@class="page-sizer fr"]/a[@class="page-numbers current"]').text
requirednumberofposts = 30
numberofpagesclick = requirednumberofposts / int(noofquestionsperpage)

if numberofpagesclick > 1:
    for i in range(numberofpagesclick):
        for j in range(int(noofquestionsperpage)):
            xpath = "//div[@id='questions']/div[" + \
                str(j + 1) + "]/div[2]/h3/a"
            print driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).get_attribute('href')
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//div[@class="pager fl"]/a[6]/span[@class="page-numbers next"]').click()
    except:
        print "All questons loaded"
```